# simpleXML parsing

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I'm trying to parse some XML using `simpleXML` in PHP.

The problem I'm having though, is that some nodes have values like `Milk & Cheese` and I'm getting a parse error.

What's the easiest way of parsing XML using simpleXML with chars such as & and / being present?

Thanks

EDIT:

I'm using:

```
 $source = 'stockdata.xml';
 $stock =  simplexml_load_file($source);

foreach($stock->StockItem as $item)
{
 ........
}
```

Comment: -1 is kinda rough here, even before the last edit. +1 unless I hear otherwise

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**quick solution:**

```
$xml = str_replace('&','&amp;',$xml); //$xml is the content in string format
```

**a better solution:** [ if you control the xml ]

add CDATA in the xml tags

```
<name><![CDATA[ Milk & honey]]></script>
```

and you'll need to tell SimpleXml to take care of the CDATA:

```
$sxml = simplexml_load_file('myfile.xml','SimpleXMLElement', LIBXML_NOCDATA);
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Had to change the way XML was read using `file_get_contents`. All seems to be ok now.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use [XML (and HTML) entities](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp). Instead of `Milk & Cheese` use `Milk &amp; Cheese`. You can find a complete list at [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_entities.asp).

Comment: the php function to do this is htmentites().  So you can do: $str = htmlentities($str, ENT_QUOTES, $encoding);  ENT_QUOTES indicates how it should deal with quotes, and $encoding is optional, but if you know it's good to include.